# No animations/selections in Tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, tabs

I am trying to implement a tabview with the nice gradual change from one view to another animation and have the current tab highlighted. At current all I can get is the basic tabview that functions, but does instant switching of tabs and no highlighting of selections. Here is my current code:

```
package com.example.ex.test;
public class MainActivity extends navBar {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            smithingTable.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            smithingTable2.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
            Map.class, null);
}
}
```

meanwhile in my activity main I have:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in tab1 for example (tab2 is the same but with slight variation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DeviceFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/newcomer_map" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I needed to add pageviews/listeners

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you use Material Design Tabs, it alredy has nice transitions and its much more customizable.

 Here's a very good [post](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) on how to implement it